# xdebug doesn't work in Mac OS X 10.7 platform with Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to configure and let work xdebug on mac os x 10.7 where it is installed Mamp and netbeans 7.1. I added to `php.ini` file

```
[xdebug]

xdebug.default_enable=1

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1

zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
```

and deactivate Zend but despite all netbeans show the message as Xdebug it is not activate and  in phpinfo() I didn't see any gui about xdebug.

Comment: This is a bit difficult to answer, as you don't mention where you get your xdebug.so from. Did you compile it yourself, how did you compile it, did you use the instructions on http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php ?

Comment: @Derick I said I have MAMP installed so xdebug is installed in MAMP and is located in the folder I mentioned

Comment: Hmm... well, I've got xdebug working on lion w/ Netbeans 7.  Though I'm not using zend.  I do remember it being a major PITA to get working, and I don't quite remember how I did it :(

Comment: Nohting to done...I had tried anything...I pretty sure the php.ini is correct I had done everything remain a mistery

Comment: "xdebug is installed in MAMP" still doesn't tell me where xdebug.so *came* from. "Not using Zend" also makes no sense to me, as PHP runs on the Zend Engine (and you didn't say whether you meant Server, Engine or Framework!).

Answer (score 0):

The path to the .so file seems wrong. Make sure it exists. In my MAMP installation it lives (for PHP5.3) in

```
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
```

Also don't forget to restart MAMP after changing it.